# Student Result based on passed and failed remarks using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that stores students exam results. In that table I have a `nvarchar` column `REMARKS`; if obtained marks are less then passing marks, the system adds `Pass/Fail` to `Remarks` in that particular column.

The problem is now I am showing whole result with total marks obtained and also display if a student has passed or failed, based on the a query like

```
If remarks = 'Fail'
```

and fail is more than one subject in that exam than display Fail else Pass. I searched and tried a lot but no luck. can anyone please tell me how to get it done?

Thanks!

UPDATE: 
Tried so far:

```
SELECT 
    StudentName,
    Year,
    ExamType,
    SUM(TotalMarks) AS TotalMarks,
    SUM(ObtainedMarks) AS ObtMarks  
FROM 
    [dbo].[Exam]
WHERE
    ExamType = @Type AND Year = @Year
```

Looking for a query something like:

```
CASE WHEN [Remarks] = 'Fail' and having count > 1  THEN 'Fail' ELSE 'Pass' End as 'Status'
```

Comment: Please add sample data, an expected result & what you have tried so far.

Comment: Use Case statement for this

Comment: @dan please see the updated question. need a query like this. but this is not working.

Comment: Can you post the entire query you've tried and not just the `case` statement.

Comment: @Jens i have table with columns Subject, Total marks, Obtained marks and passing marks. if obtained marks are less than passing marks than "Fail" is entered in the remarks column. now i want to show the whole result with total obtained marks and also mention is student is failed or passed based on in how many subjects that student has remarks "Failed" if its more than one than it should display Fail else Pass. Hope you understand my question.

Comment: Are Total marks and Obtained marks the same value?

Comment: @鄭有維 actually not. Obtained marks can vary.

Comment: @Mureinik please see the edited question i have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query returns 'fail' is there is more than one fail in the `ExamType` and `year` for a student

```
SELECT StudentName
  ,@Year
  ,@Type
  ,Sum(TotalMarks) as TotalMarks
  ,Sum(ObtainedMarks) as ObtMarks  
  ,CASE WHEN Count(CASE WHEN [Remarks] = 'Fail' THEN 1 END) > 1 THEN 'Fail' ELSE 'Pass' End as 'Status'
FROM [dbo].[Exam]
Where ExamType = @Type And Year = @Year
Group by StudentName
```

Comment: Need "Group by StudentName,Year,ExamType"

Comment: @RadimBača thanks for your kind help but its showing error between then query "(CASE WHEN [Remarks] = 'Fail' THEN 1) under closing bracket saying incorrect syntax near ')'"

Comment: @RadimBača Works perfect! Thanks a million!!

Comment: @RadimBača can we also get count and names of subjects failed?

Comment: just add one more field in result:
,Count(CASE WHEN [Remarks] = 'Fail' THEN 1 end) FailedRecords

Comment: BTW, Are you sure you need ">1" , not ">=1" condition - if 1 or more records with Fail?, not 2 or more

Comment: @omer the names of failed subjects will be more tricky, however, it is possible to solve it using subselect and FOR XML. I can try later

Comment: @PavelBiryukov its if more than one condition so ">1"  or in other words you can say ">=2 "is correct.

Comment: @RadimBača No problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: @omer which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @RadimBača SQL Server 2014